# Ubuntu won't boot, not sure what I did this time!

Tags: boot, dual-boot

Let me vent for a sec and then I'll ask my question. This is the last straw with me and Ubuntu. I reinstalled this OS about 10 times, other times I've successfully fixed it's booting issues (about 3 times), and now it's messing with me again.

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04 and haven't had any issues until now since upgrading. Last thing I remember doing was renaming partitions and deleting an exFAT partition or whatever and that was supposed to be for games, but couldnt get Steam to read it. I've tried setting nomodeset, uncommenting waylandenabled=false, and uninstalling nvidia drivers, afterwards doing sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall. This has fixed the issues in the past when I didnt have to completely reinstall, so idk what else to do. I've been on Linux for a while now, but still consider myself a noob (as I'm sure you can tell).

Some the error is cut off, but what I'm getting when booting is:

```
[Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does not cover t sponse buffer.
You are in emergency mode.
```

I love Ubuntu, but can't put up with this stress anymore. Sometimes I feel like the Ubuntu Gods are just messing with me. Probably just that I have no idea what I'm doing still, but either way my Ubuntu days are coming to an end it seems. I sadly won't be reinstalling if I can't get it to work this time. Please help!!!

Comment: As a quick fix, to simply get you working again, would you consider installing 18.04 as it is an LTS ? I only suggest this as you say your a noob and it is fair to say that one needs an apetite for troubleshooting. If you are as stressed as you sound then install another OS (I am guessing Windows) so you can just get your stuff done. How did you upgrade and from what version ?

Comment: You deleted a partition; where was it mounted? (ie. was there anything useful on it you deleted) and then did you remove it from your file system table (/etc/fstab)?

Comment: I usually love troubleshooting. So many issues that I had to learn to fix which is part of why I came to love Linux, because I actually solved most of them. This problem keeps coming back to haunt me though. I think I had these issues with LTS as well. I upgraded from 18.10, and maybe even 18.04 before that. As to the other question, It was on my SSD, all that was on it was Rocket League, and I didn't remove it from fstab.

Answer (score 0):

Guiverc's comment fixed it. Just had to remove the line from /etc/fstab I added when first trying to mount the partition, and now it works!